# Dynamically add to TR class value from selected option

Tags: jquery

Probably an easy task but I can not find a working solution?

I need to add a class value from a selected option to relative TR:

```
<table>
<tr class="odd views-row-first">
<td class="views-field views-field-website-id">1</td>
<td class="views-field views-field-changed">1349422708</td>
<td class="views-field views-field-created">1349422708</td>
<td class="views-field views-field-title">Double field</td>
<td class="views-field views-field-field-rules-conditional  views-field-editablefield">
<div id="editablefields-field-rules-conditional" class="editablefield-item">

<select id="edit-field-rules-conditional-0-field-rules-conditional-und" name="field_rules_conditional[0][field_rules_conditional][und]" class="form-select">
<option value="_none">- None -</option>
<option value="green">green</option>
<option value="red">red</option>
<option value="blue" selected="selected">blue</option>
</select>

</div>         
</td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

What I want to have:

```
<tr class="odd views-row-first blue">
```

Comment: it's not a good practice to have classes named "blue", "red" etc. becuse later if you change the color then the class name will be misleading and you have to search and replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `index` function will solve your problem.try following :

```
  $("#edit-field-rules-conditional-0-field-rules-conditional-und option").click(function(){
         var index = $("option",$("#edit-field-rules-conditional-0-field-rules-conditional-und")).index($(this));
        var $td = $("#tableId tr:eq(0) td:eq(" + index + ")");            
        $td.addClass($(this).attr("value"));
    });
```

**Edit**: give your table an Id as well.i have used "tableId" in the example,so replace with one you want.

Comment: check updated version here http://jsfiddle.net/Vwtg9/5/   OR  maybe this  http://jsfiddle.net/Vwtg9/6/

Comment: Thx it works but it adds value as class to td but i need to tr